# How do I redirect a specific URL/ROUTE/PATH/LOCATION to another?

Tags: linux, networking, url, redirection

Say my client (current device) wants to connect to a URL, say `foo.bar.com/spam/eggs/123`, how do I serve or redirect to another specified URL, say `127.0.0.1:8080`, and prevent the client from reaching `foo.bar.com/spam/eggs/123`?

What software can I use?

Comment: What operating system are you using ? please provide more information

Comment: I am using linux @Saxtheowl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your setup, you have some external domain, example.com, controlled by a 3rd party, with a website running on it, controlled by someone else.  You want to allow access to that site generally, but block certain URLs.

There are a few solutions to this; they all boil down to some sort of proxy server. You would proxy web traffic via this proxy server and have a block/redirect list configured in it, which would deal with predefined exceptions.

One free solution is squid caching proxy, which does have redirectors support (here are details in the documentation - https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors).  Do note though that it's very much not trivial to set this up correctly and maintain it.  No disrespect, but based on the fact that you had to ask this question, I suspect you may struggle to do this successfully.

Comment: I don't see how asking for a software recommendation led to a conclusion of incompetency

Answer (score 1):

You should use a reverse proxy like `Nginx` first install it sudo `apt-get install nginx` then go to the configuration file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/foo.bar.conf` and put this inside:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.bar.com;

    location /spam/eggs/123 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

then enable it with `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/foo.bar.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

With this configuration, when a client tries to connect to foo.bar.com/spam/eggs/123, Nginx will redirect the request to http://127.0.0.1:8080

then reload Nginx `sudo systemctl reload nginx`

Comment: it is always better not to modify existing distribution-installed files it possible, but to add your own alongside into the configuration drop directory (so a package update won't disturb it, for example). In this case, better put this content into `/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/foo.bar.conf` and enable it with `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/foo.bar.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. Also restart is not required, reload is enough.

Comment: I downvoted this because it doesn't answer the question and doesn't work.